# Show the all the rows of the textarea when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I show the all the  rows of the textarea when the page loads. (For example if the page loads in the textarea will only reveal 2 rows but if you click on it and edit it, it will reveal the other rows of textarea)

html

```
<textarea cols = "20" id = "textarea">

uhawefhuaewfuhaweufihwaeuifhaweiuhfawuiefhawieuf

</textarea>
```

css

```
<style>

textarea{
resize: none !important;
overflow:hidden;
border: none;
}      

</style>
```

I tried a little bit of jquery and either I did it incorectly or this just won't work.

```
<script>

var height = document.getElementById('commentinput<?php echo $commentid?>').scrollHeight;
$('#commentinput<?php echo $commentid?>').css({"height": height + "px;"});

</script>

dis for yall ->  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know jQuery very well, but your approach should work fine in simple JavaScript:

```
const commentInput = document.querySelector('#commentinput');
const commentInputHeight = commentInput.scrollHeight;
commentInput.style.height = `${commentInputHeight}px`;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just using simple js was the solution!